# Noether's Theorem - problem with a proof.

Tags: calculus

I am having difficulty working through a proof for Noether's theorem. A small portion was left as an exercise for the reader but unfortunately the answers skip on the part that I am having trouble with and just handwave through it.

From the transformed functional
$$(1)\quad\quad \hat G = \int_{\hat c}^{\hat d} d\hat x F\left(\hat x, \hat y, \frac{d\hat y}{d \hat x}\right) $$
Where
$$\hat d = d + \delta \phi (d),\quad \hat c = c +\delta \phi (c), \quad \phi (c,y(c),y'(c))) $$
and the transformation
$$ \hat x = x +\delta\phi(x,y,y') + O(\delta ^2), \quad \hat y = y + \delta\psi(x,y,y') + O(\delta^2)$$
We have to change the integration variable and limits, besides expanding F.

Using the chain rule on the transformation we have
$$\frac{d \hat y}{d \hat x} = \left(\frac{dy}{dx}+\delta \frac{d \psi}{dx}\right)\frac{dx}{d \hat x}$$
but 
$$(2)\quad\quad\frac{d \hat x}{dx}= 1+ \delta \frac{d \phi}{dx} \quad so \quad \frac{dx}{d \hat x} = 1- \delta \frac{d \phi}{dx} +O(\delta ^2)$$
and so to first order we have
$$ \frac{d \hat y}{d \hat x} = \left(\frac{dy}{dx}+\delta \frac{d \psi}{dx}\right)\left(1-\delta \frac{d \phi}{dx}\right) = \frac{dy}{dx}+\delta \left(\frac{d \psi}{dx}-\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d \phi}{dx}\right)$$
thus (1) becomes
$$(3)\quad\quad \hat G = \int_{c}^{d} dx \frac{d \hat x}{dx}F\left(x+\delta \phi, y+\delta \psi, \frac{dy}{dx}+\delta\left(\frac{d \phi}{dx}-\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d \phi}{dx}\right)\right) $$

The next step is to expand this to first order in delta and this is where I become a bit stuck!

So far I get that if you substitute (2) into (3) then notice that $\hat{G}$ is independent of $\delta$ then we must have 
$$0 = \delta\int_{c}^{d} dx \frac{d \phi}{dx}F\left(x+\delta \phi, y+\delta \psi, \frac{dy}{dx}+\delta\left(\frac{d \phi}{dx}-\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d \phi}{dx}\right)\right)$$

Some expansion should lead to...
$$ 0 = \delta \int_{c}^{d}dx\left(\left(F-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\frac{d \phi}{dx} +\phi \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\psi \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\frac{d \phi}{dx}\right)$$
But I am unsure as to how to do the expansion. I feel like I am missing something pretty obvious.